# if A = {a,b,c} . Prove OR disprove that P(A) "power set of A" is a group under the union operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

So my thinking is that

$$P(A) = \{\{\emptyset\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\} $$

although it's clearly closed under union , assiociatve and the identity exists which is the empty set but still it's not a group since there are no inverses exists for any of the elements except for that of the empty set itself.

But is that valid to say , I mean how can I do it more rigorously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty set is the identity but $B\cup C$ contains $B$ so if $B$ is non empty $B\cup C$ is non empty.  Hence a nonempty element is not invertible.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that inverses exist. Then:

$\{a\}\cup\{b,c\}=\{a,b,c\}=\{a,b\}\cup\{b,c\}\Rightarrow\{a\}=\{a,b\}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is valid as it stands.

It would be more compact to say that

$$\forall x \in P(\left\{a,b,c\right\} : a \in x\cup a 
$$ so the empty set cannot be the identity element, and then show that
any other element can't be the identity either.

Answer (score 0):

may be worth noting in this context that the power set of $X$ **is** a group under the operation of **disjoint union**, with the empty set as identity. if the complement of $A \subset X$ is $A'$ then the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$ is:
$$
A \circ B = (A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B)
$$
proving associativity is a nice exercise, though it follows much more simply if the disjoint union is viewed as ordinary addition (mod 2) in $\mathbb{F}_2^X$

Comment: That's not [the usual definition of "disjoint union"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union), and indeed I've never heard that called the "disjoint union" before; instead, [**symmetric difference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) is the standard term. Do you have a source for your usage? (It is, confusingly, rarely called the "*disjunctive union*", but that's not the same as "*disjoint* union.")

Comment: you are right, i should have used "symmetric difference". just a senior moment,  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

Let $~ X= \{1,2,3\}~$ and $~P(X)~$ be the power set of $~X~$. Examine if $~P(X)~$ is a group under the composition $~*~$ defined by $$~A*B= A\cup B ,~~~~~~~ \forall A,B \in P(X)~.$$

Comment: Use LaTeX please: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020