# Ring structure on power set of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a non empty set. Let $P(A)$ denote the power set of $A$.

$P(A)$ can be given a group structure in multiple ways.

**1.** **Using Disjoint union a group operation** [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/960089/581242)

> may be worth noting in this context that the power set of $X$
>   **is** a group under the operation of **disjoint union**, with
>   the empty set as identity. if the complement of $A \subset X$ is $A'$
>   then the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$ is: $$ A \circ B = (A \cap B')
>  \cup (A' \cap B) $$ proving associativity is a nice exercise, though
>   it follows much more simply if the disjoint union is viewed as
>   ordinary addition (mod 2) in $\mathbb{F}_2^X$

**2. Using Symmetric Difference as Group Operation** [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267782/581242)

> The power set $G$ of any set $A$ becomes an *abelian group* under the
>   operation of symmetric difference:
>
> - Why abelian? Easy to justify, just use the definition in $(1)$ above: it's defined in a way that $g_1 \triangle g_2$ means exactly
>     the same set as  $g_2 \triangle g_1$, for any two $g \in G$.
> - As you note, the symmetric difference on $G$ is associative, which can be shown using the definition in $(1)$, by showing for any $f, g,
>   > h \in G, (f\; \triangle\; g) \triangle \;h = f\;\triangle\; (g
>   > \;\triangle\; h)$.
> - The *empty set is the identity* of the group (it would be good to justify this this, too), and
> - *every element in this group is its own inverse.* (Can you justify this, as well? Just show for any $g_i \in G, g_i\;\triangle \; g_i =
>   > \varnothing$).

**Question: Can we define a ring structure on power set of $A$.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the "disjoint union" alluded to by David Holden means "disjunctive union" which is a synonym for the symmetric difference. So, you aren't listing multiple ways, really.

> Can we define a ring structure on power set of A.

As the [wiki clearly states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference):
*The power set of any set becomes a Boolean ring with symmetric difference as the addition of the ring and intersection as the multiplication of the ring.*

This is the standard ring structure on the powerset of a set.  It may have other ring structures, but none would arise so naturally as this one, and would probably not have meaningful connection to the fact the underlying set is a powerset.

Comment: This is offtopic but what do  people(mathematician) mean when they say that this "structure arises naturally". Is it related to category theory or it is just an expression.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician There is a precise meaning in category theory, but here I just mean it as an expression of natural language. I just mean that when looked at from a certain perspective, it's fairly obvious, and there aren't really any other competing structures, so it jumps out at us.